# Headers missing even if explicitly specified when reading .ORC file with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, orc

This appears to be a trivial problem without a clear solution.  I have an ORC file that, if it were represented as a CSV file, would look like this:

```
Animal,Name
Dog,Valentino
Cat,Meowser
```

et cetera. I can read in the `.orc` file in with the line:

`df_animals = spark.read.orc(path="animals.orc")`

in the sense that it produces a valid dataframe, but it includes the headers in the data as though they were data, producing the following dataframe:

```
+---------+---------------+
|      _c0|            _c1|
+---------+---------------+
|   Animal|           Name|
|      Dog|      Valentino|
|      Cat|        Meowser|
```

Clearly this isn't what I need, because I won't be able to refer to any of the actual column names.  However, I've tried:

`spark.read.option("inferSchema", True).orc("animals.orc")`

`spark.read.option("header", True).orc("animals.orc")`

`spark.read.format("orc").load("animals.orc", schema=defined_schema)`

where `defined_schema` is a valid schema constructed using `StructTypes` & `StructFields` - but the result is always the same, a dataframe that looks like the example above.  I'm aware that I can use `withColumnRenamed` to force them to certain strings, but that feels hacky and should be unnecessary given the headers in the file.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I have little experience with ORC but I frequently use parquet and my experience there is that the metadata (like column names) are kept in a separate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out of the box, you don't need any parameters for this. (OrcRelation class takes care of inferring the schema if one is not provided.) And your column names should never end up among the rows. You should check your input files, the problem is almost certainly there.

Comment: This is correct.  In generating the ORC files from the original CSVs, I didn't use the `headers=True` flag when reading in the original CSV.  Once I made that change, the ORC file had proper headers.